# How do I count the number of unique elements in an array of objects using the object property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have an array that looks like this:

```
let arr = [
    {'option1':1},{'option1':1},{'option1':1},
    {'option1':2},{'option1':2},
    {'option1':3},
    {'option2':1},{'option2':1}
]
```

I need to iterate through the array and count the occurrences of each element with the same property to be displayed like this:

```
   option1:{
            1:3,
            2:2,
            3:1,
           },
   option2:{
            1:2,
           }
```

Basically saying that option1 with a property of 1 has 3 counts, option1 with a property of 2 has 2 counts, option1 with a property of 3 has 1 count and so on.

Comment: Is there any relevance to the way you grouped the array elements on different rows? I'm asking because in JavaScript line breaks don't matter between array elements. The array is the same if written with each item on the same row or with them on separate rows. Also, the logic behind the expected result is quite obscure. Please explain the logical steps required to get from the data you're showing to the expected result.

Comment: hello @tao, there is no relevance on how I grouped the array to the question. I only did it so I can view the array clearer. I have updated the question to explain the output better

Comment: Your `option1` count was `1:3, 2:1, 3:1` before the edit. Now it's clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way...

```js
let arr = 
  [ { option1: 1 }, { option1: 1 }, { option1: 1 } 
  , { option1: 2 }, { option1: 2 } 
  , { option1: 3 } 
  , { option2: 1 }, { option2: 1 } 
  ] 

let obj = arr.reduce((r,o)=>
  {
  let [name,num] = Object.entries(o)[0] 
  if (!r[name]) r[name] = {}
  if (!r[name][num]) r[name][num] = 1
  else               r[name][num]++
  return r
  },{})

console.log( obj )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```